# How to populate Text Fields after clicking a Record in TableView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Is there a way on how to populate text fields base on the record that was clicked in the tableView in JavaFX? 

I want to display the records that I clicked in the tableview to the text fields. 
Any suggestions that would help me?

Comment: I have a few questions: what do you mean by "populating" a textfield?;  What is a "record" to you?

Comment: for example i have a record in the tableview with i click 1 column I want the record to display the records inside the textfield.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code sample for you,

```
yourTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<T>() {
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> ov, T t, T t1) {
      System.out.println(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
      //Code to populate your popup/window.
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Shreyas Dave, can you please complete the code.if where will i put it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an active listener to table view, and a method to control what it should do.

so in your FXML file you would have your tableview assigning the mouse clicked event with the method name "clickMe":

```
<TableView fx:id="someTable" layoutX="322.0" layoutY="73.0" onMouseClicked="#clickMe">
        <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="someColumn1" text="someValue1" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="someColumn2" text="someValue2" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="someColumn3" text="someValue3" />
        </columns>
</TableView>
```

next in your controller you would need to add the tableview, and fields at the top, then the clickMe method. I assume you've already added the columns and are using the cell factory to populate them:

```
package YourPackage;

public class YourFXMLController{
@FXML private TableView<objectTheTableIsPopulatedWith> someTable; //make sure the name 
// on the tableview and columns match your fx:id
@FXML private TableColumn someColumn1;
@FXML private TableColumn someColumn2;
@FXML private TableColumn someColumn3;
@FXML private TextField someField1;
@FXML private TextField someField2;
@FXML private TextField someField3;

//next add the clickMe method
public void clickMe(MouseEvent event) {
if (event.getClickCount() == 1) //Check for a click, change to 2 for double click
    {
someField1.setText(someTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getSomeString1());
someField2.setText(someTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getSomeString2());
someField3.setText(someTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getSomeString3());
    }
}
}
```

This is all provided you've already made an observable list being built by an object class with a constructor, with setters, and getters. so the getSomeString1() methods would be whatever the getters were that you used to populate the table view values.